# Consulta SQL Server y c# por rango de fecha y horas

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

tengo una base de datos la cual tiene un campo DateTime el cual contiene datos almacenados por minuto, necesito crear una consulta la cual mediante un dateTimePicker selecciones el día y mediante otros dos dateTimePicker en modo Time selecciones las dos horas o minutos entre los que consultar los datos. Había intentado lo siguiente pero me da error al intentar convertir a dateTime el string pasado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 void buscarDatosMinutales()
    {
        string fechaDesde = dateDatosMinutalesDesde.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string horaDesde = fechaDesde + timeMinutalesDesde.Value.ToString(fechaDesde + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");
        string horaHasta = fechaDesde + timeMinutalesHasta.Value.ToString( fechaDesde + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");


        string query = "SELECT * FROM mensuales WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '" + horaDesde + "' AND '" + horaHasta + "' ";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridMinutales.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También he intentado parsear a DateTime del siguiente modo:

```
  void buscarDatosMinutales()
    {
        string fechaDesde = dateDatosMinutalesDesde.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string horaDesde = fechaDesde + timeMinutalesDesde.Value.ToString(fechaDesde + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");
        string horaHasta = fechaDesde + timeMinutalesHasta.Value.ToString( fechaDesde + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");
        DateTime Fecha1 = DateTime.Parse(horaDesde);
        DateTime Fecha2 = DateTime.Parse(horaHasta);

        string query = "SELECT * FROM mensuales WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN '" + Fecha1 + "' AND '" + Fecha2 + "' ";
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGridMinutales.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Obteniendo la siguiente excepción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es una buena práctica concatenar parametros de esa forma, porque pueden inyectarte código SQL allí y ejecutar comandos que no deseas.

Lo más seguro es utilizar procedimientos almacenados, o si eso no es posible, usar SqlParameter con los SqlCommand, por ejemplo:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM mensuales WHERE FechaHora BETWEEN @FechaDesde and @FechaHasta";
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conexion);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cn);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@FechaDesde", 
    Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format(dateDatosMinutalesDesde.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + string.Format(timeMinutalesDesde.Text, "HH:mm"))));
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@FechaHasta", 
    Convert.ToDateTime(string.Format(dateDatosMinutalesHasta.Text, "yyyy-MM-dd") + " " + string.Format(timeMinutalesHasta.Text, "HH:mm"))));
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
dataGridMinutales.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Buenas, me salta error en el primer conver.toDateTime: System.Format.Exception: 'No se puede reconocer la cadena como valor DateTimeVálido'

Comment: @mourazo no estoy seguro pero esta mal tu formato hh:mi:ss.mmmm debe ser hh:mm:ss.mmmm

Comment: Funciono, solo debía añadir el formato a dateTimePicker timeMinutalesDesde.value.ToString("hh:mm:ss"). Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Si estas usando los controles nativos de winform, datetimepicker, te modifique el codigo para que puedas convertirlos a datetime a partir de ellos.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta agregar este codigo haber si te funciona tal vez solo sea eso

```
string horaDesde = fechaDesde + ' ' +timeMinutalesDesde.Value.ToString(fechaDesde  + ' ' + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");
string horaHasta = fechaDesde + ' ' +timeMinutalesHasta.Value.ToString( fechaDesde  + ' ' + "hh:mi:ss.mmm");
```

Comment: me da el mismo error